# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore maximum size

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, icloud

What is the maximum size of the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

I have seen conflicting reports, for example the [current iOS documentation says 1mb](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html):

However, if you search on Google you can see many references to the maximum size being 64kb:

- [Sync preference data with
  iCloud](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/10/24/sync-preference-data-with-icloud.html)
- [Beginning IOS 5 Application
  Development](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YeTFvTeeEwAC&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore+64kb)

I'm pretty sure the answer is that it used to be 64kb and was increased at some point.
Does anyone know if this is the case, and if so when the change was made and if it affects all devices or just ones on a specific iOS (e.g. 5.1 but not 5.0?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple say that:

> The key-value store is not intended for storing large amounts of data.
>   It is intended for storing configuration data, preferences, and small
>   amounts of app-related data

Which leads me to think that if you're asking this question you probably shouldn't be using the key-value store.

Having said that, Apple have just [updated their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=05302012a) with newer, higher limits:

> We've increased the storage limits for iCloud Key Value Store so you
>   can provide an even better experience in your app. Now, the total Key
>   Value Storage limit is 1 MB per app, the single key limit is 1 MB, and
>   the total key limit is 1024.

I'm not sure when that took effect but that probably explains the discrepancy between the various sources.

Comment: I had the app originally coded to use Core Data iCloud sync but found that iCloud sync of Core Data just doesn't work reliably yet. Reading through the devforums and looking at app crashes and hung points I decided to refactor and store user favourites in NSUSerdefaults synced via iCloud instead. This is much more reliable, and in fact much faster as well.

Comment: If you're just storing user favourites, why does the limit matter? Seems to me that even 64Kb is way more than you'd need for a few references.

Comment: I noticed the documentation change on the developer portal re key value store limit, and came back to the question to add the link but saw you already had done it. Cheers :)